# Vectorizing an operation between all pairs of elements in two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, geometry, combinations

Given two arrays where each row represents a circle (x, y, r):

```
data = {}
data[1] = np.array([[455.108, 97.0478, 0.0122453333],
                    [403.775, 170.558, 0.0138770952],
                    [255.383, 363.815, 0.0179857619]])
data[2] = np.array([[455.103, 97.0473, 0.012041],
                    [210.19, 326.958, 0.0156912857],
                    [455.106, 97.049, 0.0150472381]])
```

I would like to pull out all of the pairs of circles that are not disjointed. This can be done by:

```
close_data = {}
for row1 in data[1]: #loop over first array
    for row2 in data[2]: #loop over second array
        condition = ((abs(row1[0]-row2[0]) + abs(row1[1]-row2[1])) < (row1[2]+row2[2])) 
        if condition: #circles overlap if true
            if tuple(row1) not in close_data.keys():                           
                close_data[tuple(row1)] = [row1, row2] #pull out close data points
            else:
                close_data[tuple(row1)].append(row2)

for k, v in close_data.iteritems():
    print k, v 
#desired outcome   
#(455.108, 97.047799999999995, 0.012245333299999999)
#[array([  4.55108000e+02,   9.70478000e+01,   1.22453333e-02]), 
# array([  4.55103000e+02,   9.70473000e+01,   1.2040000e-02]), 
# array([  4.55106000e+02,   9.70490000e+01,   1.50472381e-02])]
```

However the multiple loops over the arrays are very inefficient for large datasets. Is it possible to vectorize the calculations so I get the advantage of using numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most difficult bit is actually getting to your representation of the info. Oh, and I inserted a few squares. If you really don't want Euclidean distances you have to change back.

```
import numpy as np

data = {}
data[1] = np.array([[455.108, 97.0478, 0.0122453333],
                    [403.775, 170.558, 0.0138770952],
                    [255.383, 363.815, 0.0179857619]])
data[2] = np.array([[455.103, 97.0473, 0.012041],
                    [210.19, 326.958, 0.0156912857],
                    [455.106, 97.049, 0.0150472381]])

d1 = data[1][:, None, :]
d2 = data[2][None, :, :]
dists2 = ((d1[..., :2] - d2[..., :2])**2).sum(axis = -1)
radss2 = (d1[..., 2] + d2[..., 2])**2

inds1, inds2 = np.where(dists2 <= radss2)

# translate to your representation:

bnds = np.r_[np.searchsorted(inds1, np.arange(3)), len(inds1)]
rows = [data[2][inds2[bnds[i]:bnds[i+1]]] for i in range(3)]
out = dict([(tuple (data[1][i]), rows[i]) for i in range(3) if rows[i].size > 0])
```

Comment: Will have a look soon, thanks! I am by no means married to the final representation, I really just need a way of collating all of the connected circles in groups and the way I had it seemed a natural way to pull it out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure numpythonic way (`a` is `data[1]` and `b` is `data[2]`):

```
In [80]: p = np.arange(3) # for creating the indices of combinations using np.tile and np.repeat

In [81]: a = a[np.repeat(p, 3)] # creates the first column of combination array

In [82]: b = b[np.tile(p, 3)] # creates the second column of combination array

In [83]: abs(a[:, :2] - b[:, :2]).sum(1) < a[:, 2] + b[:, 2]
Out[83]: array([ True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```